# Let $H_n$ be the number of heads of fliping n fair coins, let $X_n=e^{-H_n}$, and let $Y=0$. Prove that $X_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

[image]
This is my attempt.

I only need to prove for any $\epsilon$, $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}P(|X_n|\ge \epsilon)=0\implies  \lim_{n\to \infty}P(e^{-H_n}\ge \epsilon)=0$$

That is, I need to prove $$\lim_{n\to \infty}P(H_n\le -\ln\epsilon)=0  \ \ \ (1)$$

It's clear that since $H_n$ denotes the number of heads, $H_n\ge 0$, if $\epsilon >1$, the probability is zero automatically.

Thus we only need to consider $\epsilon\le 1$

Then I think I should use the weak law of large numbers (WLLN). I can let $H_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i$ is a random variable such that $X_i=1$ if the coin shows the head and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then,(since each $\{X_i\}$ is i.i.d and each has the same mean) by WLLN , I have, for any $\epsilon$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|H_n-\dfrac{n}{2}|\ge \epsilon)=0 \ \ \ (2)$$

Then I think I need to connect $(1)$ and $(2)$. But I'm kind of getting stuck here.

I think the usual trick for this kind of problem is to make "$ H_n<-\ln \epsilon$" be a subevent of a larger event $A_n$, then we show $\lim_{n\to \infty }P(A_n)=0$. Then this implies that $ \lim_{n\to \infty}P(H_n\le -\ln\epsilon)=0$

Then I tried to use $(2)$. Since it is true for any $\epsilon$, in particular, I let $\epsilon = -\ln \epsilon $ where the second $\epsilon\le 1$. Thus I have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|H_n-\dfrac{n}{2}|\ge -\ln \epsilon)=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(H_n\ge \dfrac{n}{2}-\ln \epsilon \ or \ H_n \le \dfrac{n}{2}+\ln \epsilon)=0 $$.

In $(1)$ it is "$H_n\le -\ln \epsilon$", so I want to make that $-\ln \epsilon < \dfrac{n}{2}+\ln \epsilon$. That is $n>-4\ln \epsilon$

Then "$H_n\le -\ln \epsilon$" is a subevent of "$H_n\le \dfrac{n}{2}+\ln \epsilon$", which is the subevent of "$H_n\ge \dfrac{n}{2}-\ln \epsilon \ or \ H_n \le \dfrac{n}{2}+\ln \epsilon$".

Thus I can say that $$P(H_n\le -\ln\epsilon)\le P(|H_n-\dfrac{n}{2}|\ge \epsilon)$$ as desired.

Is this right? If this is wrong, may I get the right answer to this question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct and also I think this is a reasonable way to approach this problem. Basically start from the intuition "We know $H_n$ should be approximately $\frac n 2$, which gets further and further away from $0$" and then use the definitions to formalize.

If you're using multiple different definitions that traditionally involve $\epsilon$, I *strongly* recommend using different variable names. You could try using stuff like $\epsilon, \hat \epsilon, \tilde \epsilon, \epsilon'$ or $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ or even just use different letters if you want. But I think it'll be really a lot easier for readers (and also yourself!) to keep track of what's going on if you avoid statements like "I let $\epsilon = - \ln(\epsilon)$".